# app keeps stopping in kitkat

Tags: android, version, android-4.4-kitkat

I have created a simple android project in studio. But it won't run in kitkat and below versions. But it works fine with lollipop+ versions. Each project I create won't run in kitkat. When I open my activity it just stopped on real device but runs properly on emulator. I cant attach my phone to the PC. So I am not able to show the errors in logcat. I tried a lot of things.

Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.demotoruninpos"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.demotoruninpos">


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: without your error log , there's nothing we can do . your code looks fine at this side .

Comment: Post your error log here @Shuchi

Comment: @Anonymous this link you mentioned . its totally different case . its multidex problem . it has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: because he has not posted any error log I am just guessing

Comment: you can check  multidex from gradle file only . which **She** has posted

Comment: I Cant connect my phone with PC. so not able to view logcat.

Comment: have you used any xml attribute that works only with api>21 like `android:elivation="1dp"`

Comment: @ShuchiSheth put your **code** so everyone  understand

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I just have created simple android project in studio. in my main activity there is only textview. nothing else. I haven't coded anything in java file also.

Comment: how you're sendimg app to your phone ?

Comment: @Tej only one tablet I can attach with PC which having lollipop version. N from Tablet I send application to another phones via xender.

Comment: ok i got your point .

Comment: try to send build apk from xender

Comment: @ShuchiSheth go to build>generate apk> use that apk for you lollipop device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having this problem because of instant run is enable in your android studio. what you have to do ....

go to

```
File > Setting > Build,Execution,Dev > Instant run > Turn it OFF.
```

now you are good to go..Happy Codding